# openlayers refresh only feature, undo dragging

Tags: controls, openlayers, drag

im working on solution to drag the features. After drag i created window to ask users if they want to let feature on this position or put it back on original location? 
There is my current solution:

First of all i get coordinates(left, bottom, right, top) from original position of the feature. 
Then i drag feature and place it. In this moment i get coordinates of the new position. 
If i dont want to place here and put it back on original location, i just add original coordinates to the feature. And here is problem. The coordinates are rewrite but feature is not located on original position. If I use refresh method, it doesnt help, because refresh method refresh whole layer, but i want to refresh (if it's possible) only current feature.

Best regards

Gabriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you could do:

- make a copy of the original feature (serialize) before it is dragged
- to undo the dragging, deserialize original feature and load it, if this worked remove dragged version

Also have a look at the cancel method, maybe it could help:

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DragFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature.cancel

Comment: Thank you first. Your comment helped me. I've created clone of the selected feature and when i wanted to put feature back, then i removed original feature from vector layer and add clone feature.